# Perl numeric comparison of numeric strings understanding and debugging

Tags: perl

I have 2 variables, x, y with "numeric" data. Note, both of these come from different sources (mysql data and parsed file data), so I am assuming firstly that they have ended up as strings.

```
## this will work fine with any data that I assign manually, so can't reproduce the issue for you here...

## $x sourced from an sql query, $y sourced from a parsed file
 
warn "test x == y, $x == $y is " . ($x == $y);
warn "test x != y, $x != $y is " . ($x != $y);
warn "test x eq y, $x eq $y is " . ($x eq $y);
warn "test x ne y, $x ne $y is " . ($x ne $y);
warn "unpack x, " . unpack 'H*', $x;
warn "unpack y, " . unpack 'H*', $y;
```

output

```
test x == y, 14 == 14 is  
test x != y, 14 != 14 is 1
test x eq y, 14 eq 14 is 1 
test x ne y, 14 ne 14 is
unpack x, 3134
unpack y, 3134
```

Unless I'm having a bad hair day, which is possible. The first two tests "appear" incorrect, as I would expect the strings to be converted to numbers and compared.

I can get around it by using "ne" rather than !=, but I want to try and understand, so I don't introduce bugs elsewhere as there's some issue I don't understand.

Note:
If I assign 14 or "14" to $y to test beforehand, all works as I'd expect. Doing the same with $x makes no difference, so I assume something is "funny" with $y.
If I assign $y = $y + 0 or similar to make sure it's a number, it makes no difference.

So as I can't reproduce the example nicely, I'm trying to understand what may be wrong, and how I can isolate what is "different" about $y or poke about at it.

Edit:
If I Devel::Peek at $x (doesn't change after comparison)

```
SV = PVNV(0xe2de4c0) at 0x101ccad8
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (IOK,NOK,POK,pIOK,pNOK,pPOK)
  IV = 14
  NV = 14
  PV = 0x447ab580 "14"\0
  CUR = 2
  LEN = 10
```

If I Devel::Peek at $y

```
SV = PVNV(0xcf94880) at 0xf039770
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (NOK,pIOK,pNOK)
  IV = 14
  NV = 14
  PV = 0
```

I also note:

```
warn ($x - $y);
output: -1.77635683940025e-15
```

Which suggests choroba is maybe correct (although why does $y need stringifying for a numeric comparison, I can see that may happen when adding to a string in debug, but not in the original). I'm a little surprised by the whole thing though, in both the fact it doesn't display the float, or any easy way to figure if that was the case.

Edit2: Interestingly, this only happens for the number 14 in the test data, number 12 for example gives the correct result, which again may make sense if there is some rounding happening. I've got around it by $x=int($x + 0.5) and $y=int($y + 0.5) as that's actually what I want the values to be.

Edit: ikegamis sprintf on $y produces

```
14.0000000000000017763568394002504646778106689453125
```

Just out of interest, I traced this all the way back to a XML::LibXML::Reader find_value() call, where the number was originally a 0.14 string and multiplied, so my mistake for not doing some proper data checking in the code.

Shouldn't Devel::Peek show the number as 14.0000000000000017763568394002504646778106689453125 under the hood ?

Edit: Just for those interested, I can manually replicate it now with setting the following, which makes the problem a bit more obvious.

```
my $x = "0.14";
$x *= 100;
my $y = 14;
```

Comment: No, you don't want to truncate (`int($x)`) Imagine if you had 13.9999999999999. You want to round.

Comment: Thanks, that was a worry actually.....so what's the correct approach here ?

Comment: If you're comparing rather than trying to fix, replace `$x == $y` with `abs( $x - $y ) < $epsilon`.

Comment: Thanks, thinking on it some more, I do want them to be treated as ints (they can't be floats in this case, otherwise I think that would be better). So I think $y = int($y+0.5) would work ok ?

Comment: Also, you can read the link in my answer on why `0.14` is not exactly `0.14`.

Comment: Thanks, it's very useful. I think my actual surprise somehow is that if the number isn't actually 0.14 why its not displayed correctly as a string (eg the printf example shows it correctly). Eg if its 14.000000...177.... why it displays 14.

Comment: A hot topic title on this question would be "Why does Perl say 14 == 14 is false?" ;) I find it interesting, but perhaps it is trivial to those who work with computer science.

Comment: @Ian: Because then you'd never see `0.14` which might be somewhat inconvenient for some other people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my $x = 14.000000000000001;
my $y = 14;
```

When stringifying a value, Perl rounds the number a bit if needed.

See also
[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: I've edited the answer with a Devel::Peek if that helps...

Comment: @Ian Using `printf "%.100g\n", $_ for $x, $y;` would confirm. Well, so does the substraction you used.

Comment: Thanks, have edited answer, which shows that info.